# How to fix FutureBuilder open multiple times error?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

these my two classes(two pages). these two classes open multiple times.
I put debug point in futurebuilder in two classes.
debug point running,

1. MainCategory page and got to the next page
2. SubCategory page and again running MainCategory page(previous page) futurebuilder and again running MainCategory page futurebuilder
3. navigate subcategory page to third page running subcategory page and main category page

I upload my two classes to GitHub and please let me know what the issue is.

MainCategory code: https://github.com/bhanuka96/ios_login/blob/master/MainCategory.dart
SubCategory code: https://github.com/bhanuka96/ios_login/blob/master/subCategory.dart

Answer (score 15):

As stated in the documentation, you should not fetch the Future for the Futurebuilder during the widget's build event.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html

> The future must have been obtained earlier, e.g. during
>   State.initState, State.didUpdateConfig, or
>   State.didChangeDependencies. It must not be created during the
>   State.build or StatelessWidget.build method call when constructing the
>   FutureBuilder. If the future is created at the same time as the
>   FutureBuilder, then every time the FutureBuilder's parent is rebuilt,
>   the asynchronous task will be restarted.

So, try to move your call to `getRegister` method outside the build method and replace it with the returned Future value.

For example, below I have a class that returns a Future value which will be consumed with the help of FutureBuilder.

```
class MyApiHelper{

  static Future<List<String>> getMyList() async {
    // your implementation to make server calls
    return List<String>();
  }
}
```

Now, inside your widget, you will have something like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  Future<List<String>> _myList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _myList = MyApiHelper.getMyList();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(body: FutureBuilder(
      future: _myList,
      builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot<List<String>> snapLs) {
        if(!snapLs.hasData) return CircularProgressIndicator();

        return ListView.builder(
          itemCount: snapLs.data.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, index) {
            //show your list item row here...
          },
        );
      },
    ));
  }
}
```

As shown above, the Future is fetched in the `initState` function and used inside the `build` method and used by `FutureBuilder`.

I hope this was helpful.
Thanks.

Comment: can you give an example

Comment: @Garrett I have edited my answer to show an example for a typical use case scenario. Good luck.

Comment: Perfect answer. Thank you

Comment: Brilliant Answer bro.

Answer (score 0):

If you happen to use Provider, here's (in my opinion) a clearer alternative based on your question:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureProvider<List<String>>(
      create: (_) => MyApiHelper.getMyList(),
      child: Consumer<List<String>>(
        builder: (_, list, __) {
          if (list == null) return CircularProgressIndicator();
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: list.length,
            itemBuilder: (_, index) {
              //show your list item row here...
            },
          );
        };
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This can also be achieved of course as a `StatefulWidget` as suggested by the other answer, or even with `flutter_hooks` as explained in [Why is my Future/Async Called Multiple Times?](https://flutterigniter.com/future-async-called-multiple-times/)

Answer (score 0):

You can create new Widget and pass Function to 
`returnFuture`  as

```
() {
 return YourFuture;
}
```

```
import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyFutureBuilder<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final Future<T> Function() returnFuture;
  final AsyncWidgetBuilder<T> builder;
  final T initialData;
  MyFutureBuilder({
    this.returnFuture,
    @required this.builder,
    this.initialData,
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyFutureBuilderState<T> createState() => _MyFutureBuilderState<T>();
}

class _MyFutureBuilderState<T> extends State<MyFutureBuilder<T>> {
  bool isLoading = false;
  Future<T> future;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    future = widget.returnFuture();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      builder: widget.builder,
      initialData: widget.initialData,
      future: future,
    );
  }
}
```

Example

````
MyFutureBuilder<List<User>>(
                                  returnFuture: () {
                                    return moderatorUserProvider
                                        .getExecutorsAsModeratorByIds(val.users,
                                            save: true);
                                  },
                                  builder: (cont, asyncData) {

                                    if (asyncData.connectionState !=
                                        ConnectionState.done) {
                                      return Center(
                                        child: MyCircularProgressIndicator(
                                          color: ModeratorColor.executors.color,
                                        ),
                                      );
                                    }
                                    return Column(
                                        children: asyncData.data
                                            .map(
                                              (singlExecutor) =>
                                                  ChooseInfoButton(
                                                title:
                                                    '${singlExecutor.firstName} ${singlExecutor.secondName}',
                                                subTitle: 'Business analyst',
                                                middleText: '4.000 NOK',
                                                subMiddleText: 'full time',
                                                label: 'test period',
                                                subLabel: '1.5 month',
                                                imageUrl:
                                                    assetsUrl + 'download.jpeg',
                                                onTap: () {
                                                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                                      builder: (_) =>
                                                          ModeratorExecutorEditPage(),
                                                    ),
                                                  );
                                                },
                                              ),
                                            )
                                            .toList());
                                  },
                                )
    ```
````